# What is the difference between EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering and not using Partitioner at all?

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, parallel.foreach

In case I have a collection of objects that each object's process takes lots of time, what is the difference between `EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering` and not using `Partitioner` at all?

[EnumerablePartitionerOptions Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions)

> **EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering:**
> Create a partitioner that takes items from the source enumerable one
> at a time and does not use intermediate storage that can be accessed
> more efficiently by multiple threads. This option provides support for
> low latency (items will be processed as soon as they are available
> from the source) and provides partial support for dependencies between
> items (a thread cannot deadlock waiting for an item that the thread
> itself is responsible for processing).

Which is faster, and why?

```
IEnumerable<int> Numbers1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
Parallel.ForEach(Numbers1, (number) => VeryExpensiveMethod(number));

//...

Partitioner<int> Numbers2 = Partitioner.Create(Enumerable.Range(1, 100),
    EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
Parallel.ForEach(Numbers2, (number) => VeryExpensiveMethod(number));
```

Comment: Using a `Partitioner` for what? Please supply a little context...

Comment: In case I have a collection of objects that each object's prosses takes lots of time,
what is the deffrence between EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering and not using  Partitioner at all?

Comment: Are you talking about not using *parallelism* at all? Maybe if you could present two small code samples of the two situations you want compared.

Answer (score 0):

Your example might not represent accurately your actual scenario, because an [`IEnumerable<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) is a sequence, not a collection. The [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) API handles differently sources that implement the [`IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1) interface from sources that don't. So if your collection is for example a `List<T>` or a `T[]`, you'll get *range partitioning*. If it's some other type like a `Queue<T>`, you'll get *chunk partitioning*. You can read in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl#kinds-of-partitioning) the difference between these types of partitionings. In the context of this question, which is calling a `VeryExpensiveMethod` for each item, it suffices to say that none of these partitioning strategies is optimal. What you really need is to balance perfectly the work between the available worker threads, and this can only be accomplished by taking items from the source collection one at a time. So using the [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) option is the correct thing to do on this scenario.

> Which is faster, and why?

Using the `EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering` is faster because it avoids the situation where a single worker thread is processing alone the last dozen of items, while all the other worker threads have returned to the `ThreadPool` doing nothing. This advantage completely dwarfs the disadvantage of the additional synchronization overhead associated with taking only one item at a time. Balancing the workload boosts the performance by seconds or minutes, while the increased synchronization harms it by microseconds or nanoseconds.